# Can I initialize a Codable Model from a different model in a Swift extension?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, designated-initializer

I have a codable model

```
public final class MyCodableModel: Codable {
  public let id: Int
}
```

I also have another model that happens to have the same variables inside it.

```
public final class MyOtherModel {
  public let id: Int
}
```

Now, I want to instantiate `MyCodableModel` using `MyOtherModel` in an extension. I don't want to modify `MyCodableModel` directly because of dependency issues.

I first tried to use a normal initializer in my extension, but it said I needed to use a `convenience initializer`, so then I ended up with this:

```
extension MyCodableModel {
  convenience init?(myOtherModel: MyOtherModel) {
    id = myOtherModel.id
  }
}
```

But the error says `'let' property 'id' may not be initialized directly; use "self.init(...)" or "self = ..." instead`. I assume this is because I'm not using the designated initializer of `init(from: Decoder)`.

Is there another way to do this? Or will I not be able to convert `MyOtherModel` to a `MyCodableModel`?

Comment: You can't do it via an extension. You would have to add the initialiser to the `MyCodableModel` class